# Android: setImageUri for compound view issue

Tags: android, imageview, android-custom-view, imageurl

I'm new to Android, I have a merged view like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8.33dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_border_top"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:includeFontPadding="true"
    android:text="0 Points"
    android:textColor="@color/GreenDark"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
<!--android:layout_height="25dp"-->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/text_border_bottom"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:includeFontPadding="true"
    android:text="New Parent !"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="9sp" />
<!--android:layout_height="16.67dp"-->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/lvl1" />
```

this is my attrs:

```
    <declare-styleable name="GamificationTagView">
    <attr name="gamePoint" format="string" />
    <attr name="levelTitle" format="string" />
    <attr name="levelLogo" format="integer" />
    <attr name="android:textColor" />
    <attr name="levelTitleVisible" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

and these are three method of its class(GamificationTagView.java):

```
    public void setGamePointText(String gamePoint) {
    SpannableString ss1 = new SpannableString(gamePoint + "  Points");
    ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, ss1.length() - 6, 0); // twice the size of gamePoint
    mGamePoint.setText(ss1);
}

public void setLevelTitleText(String levelTitle) {
    mLvlTitle.setText(levelTitle);
}

public void setIconDrawable(String url) {
    mIcon.setImageURI(Uri.parse(url));
}
```

With the same way of calling these methods , I'm able to setText as usual but I have no idea why the `mIcon.setImageURI` just doesn't work. This url link has no problem but it falls to `bad bitmap uri` and `FileNotFoundException`:

```
E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /https:/xxx/yyy.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) 09-17 00:20:06.403 7175-7175/com.qqq.rrr I/System.out﹕ resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: https://xxx/yyy.png
```

This is what I expect to get:

[image]

But this is what I got:

[image]

I want to know why is the setImageUri doesn't work for my compound view and how to solve it. Pls help and thanks in advance.